# Transcluding a text file into html via javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've been looking around at various solutions, and the 'easiest' I've found so far appears to be on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367048/1249379) comment on a similar question.

I have very little knowledge of javascript or how to implement it, so I'm stuck as to why this might not be working.

So far I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Goal, Strategy, Tactic</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function read(textFile){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET',textFile);
    xhr.onload=show;
    xhr.send()
}

function show(){
    var pre=document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent=this.response;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}

</script>
```

and in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
read('Android_String_Update.txt');
show();
//-->
</script>
```

*Android_String_Update.txt* being a text file with content. I'm also testing this out on safari 8.0 which supports [xhr2](http://caniuse.com/xhr2)

Text file content is:

Example of text in file is

```
#### Inputs
No inputs required

#### Tools
* Jenkins
* Gitlab

#### Steps
1. Navigate to the jenkins
1. Click on "Build Now"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your code on last version of Firefox, it works perfectly.
The tested code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Goal, Strategy, Tactic</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function read(textFile){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET',textFile);
    xhr.onload=show;
    xhr.send()
}

function show(){
    var pre=document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent=this.response;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}

</script>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
read('Android_String_Update.txt');
show();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Assuming you have a text file named Android_String_Update.txt in the same folder, it should work. Do you have any errors in javascript console ?

Comment: Ok I see the problem. I'm using this in conjunction with http://strapdownjs.com. All markdown has to be inside `<xmp></xmp>` tags, and when I'm passing the txt file contents (more markdown) they don't get rendered at all

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to get a markdown file, file A, to render correctly and to include markdown from file B.

Comment: what type of content do you have in your txt file ? post an example.