# Import text file into a WordPress widget using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to have a WordPress text widget with a javascript that would populate the widget with text from some .txt file (this is to allow dynamic content on a cached page by allowing me to update that text file with new HTML content).

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366191/import-text-file-using-javascript) and tried the following code, which did not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
function read(textFile){
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('GET',textFile);
    xhr.onload=show;
    xhr.send()
}

function show(){
    var pre=document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent=this.response;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}

read('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Raynos/file-store/master/temp.txt');
</script>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: What is your `show()` function doing?

Comment: This worked just fine in jsfiddle for me ... Possibly there is something else that's obstructing.

Comment: Where do you call `read`? Is the `<script>` element at Question within `<head>` element? Is `document.body` defined? Have you tried calling `read` within `window` `load` event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Javascript or are you just hoping for a copy and paste solution? Perhaps try reworking this code here:

```
function getStuff(url) {
  var xhttp, jsonData, parsedData;

  // check that we have access to XMLHttpRequest
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

     // get the data returned from the request...
     jsonData = this.responseText;
     // ...and parse it
     parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

     // return the data here
     // if the data you're returning is an object
     // you need to know the endpoints
     // for example, if there was a username,
     // you might return parsedData.username
     var something = parsedData.endpoint;
     // debug / test
     console.log(something);

     var elementToShowStuffIn = document.getElementById('theIDOfTheElement');
     elementToShowStuffIn.innerHTML = something;


    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getStuff('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Raynos/file-store/master/temp.txt');
```

Yes, this works. Just replace this line here: `var something = parsedData.foo.bar;`